# How do I add my shopping cart items to Transaction.item_list_.items

Tags: paypal

I am trying to pass over my shopping cart items to paypal using the .net REST API SDK

Below is the code:

```
            Dim b As Integer = 0
            Dim pCartItem As New PayPal.Api.Payments.Item
            Dim pCartItemList As New PayPal.Api.Payments.ItemList
            Do While b <= cart.Count - 1

                pCartItem.name = cart(b).Name
                pCartItem.price = cart(b).Price
                pCartItem.quantity = cart(b).Quantity
                pCartItem.currency = "USD"
                pCartItem.sku = cart(b).Sku
                pCartItemList.items.Add(pCartItem) 'This line errors out
                pCartItem = New PayPal.Api.Payments.Item
                b += 1
            Loop
            orderTransaction.item_list = pCartItemList
```

The line that errors out pCartItemList.items.Add(pCartItem) throws the error "Object reference not set to the instance of an object. Try using the keyword "new" :. I don't understand why because when i hover over the pCartItem in Visual Studio I am able to see all the correct values that have been assigned from my shopping cart.

Is this even the right way to add Item objects to the Transacation.item_list ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that error for anyone else who may run into this here is the code that works

```
        Dim pCartItem As PayPal.Api.Payments.Item = New PayPal.Api.Payments.Item
            orderTransaction.item_list = New PayPal.Api.Payments.ItemList
            orderTransaction.item_list.items = New List(Of PayPal.Api.Payments.Item)

            Do While b <= cart.Count - 1

                pCartItem.name = cart(b).Name
                pCartItem.price = cart(b).Price
                pCartItem.quantity = cart(b).Quantity
                pCartItem.currency = "USD"
                pCartItem.sku = cart(b).Sku
                orderTransaction.item_list.items.Add(pCartItem)
                pCartItem = New PayPal.Api.Payments.Item
                b += 1
            Loop
```